# How to extract a complete method inside a class?

Tags: c#, text, methods

I'm trying to extract a complete method which is inside a cs file.
for instance.. suppose we have a class like this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace GetMethodNm
{
class MyClass
{

    public int ComplexMethod(int param1, int myCustomValue)
    {
        if (param1 == myCustomValue)
        {
            return 54;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public string ComplexMethodV(int param1, int myCustomValue)
    {
        if (param1 < myCustomValue)
        {
            return "300";
        }
        else
        {
            return "My custom value to return";
        }
    }

    public bool ComplexMethodX(int param1, int myCustomValue)
    {
        if (param1 == myCustomValue)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then I need to extract the method reading the cs file  **ComplexMethodV** .. How can I do this? I have tried with reflection but I can only get the name and some things inside of it.. but I would need the literal method within.

Comment: you want to read the source-code? Why not simply read the file itself using a `FileStream`?

Comment: you want to read whole definition?

Comment: Do you want to invoke the method or something? Do you want all parameters to be clear before runtime or? What is the purpose? Sometimes if you give some more context people can help you better.

Comment: What do you mean by _extract_?  Reflection only gives you _metadata_ - it does not give you source code.  You'd need to _decompile_ the binary and search for that method.

Comment: You're going to have to let us know your ultimate goal because the answer may vary widely.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If you are on a newer version you can do it with Roslyn pretty easily.

Comment: Exactly .. I am able to read the whole data in a file stream.. and I need the whole method, the raw method.. This is for a optimization process in huge classes generated that have huge methods.. I need to get the whole stream but I cannot get just the snippet of code of a certain method.. in a fresh class..

Comment: Basically I want to do extract the method "ComplexMethodV" and the output would be

`code`
public string ComplexMethodV(int param1, int myCustomValue)
    {
        if (param1 < myCustomValue)
        {
            return "300";
        }
        else
        {
            return "My custom value to return";
        }
    }

Comment: @Scott is there any example you can put to extract it with Roslyn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Roslyn tasks like this are relitively easy. In a project add the NuGet package [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp), then just use the following code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

namespace SandboxConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var text = File.ReadAllText("MyClass.cs");
            var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(text);

            var method = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
                         .OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>()
                         .First(x => x.Identifier.Text == "ComplexMethodV");

            Console.WriteLine(method.ToFullString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs the text

```
        public string ComplexMethodV(int param1, int myCustomValue)
        {
            if (param1 < myCustomValue)
            {
                return "300";
            }
            else
            {
                return "My custom value to return";
            }
        }
```

See [the Wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki) for more advanced tutorials on how to do things like parse entire solutions.

Comment: Thanks for this.. Is there a way to modify this method and replace the node into the tree? Any clue will be welcome.

Comment: Yep, [there is a entire walkthough on it in the wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Getting-Started-C%23-Syntax-Transformation)